# Running Execute resource inside Ruby Block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Trying to use the code below, to make resolv.conf immutable:

```
ruby_block "immutable_resolv" do
       block do
               r = Chef::Resource::Execute.new("attr settings")
               r.command "/usr/bin/chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf"
               r.run_action(:create)
       end
       only_if { ::File.exist?('/etc/resolv.conf') }
end
```

Executing against a node returns:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[immutable_resolv]'
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `events' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone advise what's going wrong with this? I've narrowed it down to a problem with the `r.run_action` line, but unsure why it's causing the error?

Comment: Tried to run your code and it ain't runnable Ruby code. Some crucial info must be missing from the question.

Comment: Looks like ruby_block doesn't accept `only_if`  https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html

Comment: Tried commenting the `only_if` - same result unfortunately

Answer (score -2):

This is no longer an option. Write a custom resource instead. Or just use a normal resource.

Comment: When you say - 'no longer an option'. Do you have any background info as to why? Has something recently changed with regards to the usability of resources inside a Ruby block? Just trying to better understand what's going on as there doesn't seem to be a lot of `Chef::Resource::Execute.new` examples out there, to compare against...

Comment: It never really worked correctly but in days long past (like years ago) you could manually construct resource objects and fool Chef into running them. That no longer works, they really have to be created by Chef's machinery. And that means using Chef's tools rather than writing your own way.